# Spring - is it possible to give same url (path) in request mapping for two different post methods?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

Is it possible to map same path (uri) in request mapping for two different post methods, only difference is request body.

**Example**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String helloEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    return "Hello Employee";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String helloStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return "Hello Student";
  }
```

Comment: How would you know which method you want to call if the endpoints and methods are identical?

Comment: It might be helpful to give some context, this seems like an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: parameters in request body is different in each method

Comment: That's the same context again. *Why* is it different, why do you post different resources to the same endpoint?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't give same url in request mapping of post method having different request body type but same media type. Below won't work:

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/hello", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String hello(@RequestBody Pojo1 val) {
    return "Hello";
  }

  @PostMapping(path = "/hello", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String hello(@RequestBody Pojo2 val) {
    return "Hello";
  }
```

If you have different media type, then it will. Below will work:

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/hello", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String hello(@RequestBody Pojo val) {
    return "Hello";
  }

  @PostMapping(path = "/hello", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
  public String hello(@RequestBody String val) {
    return "Hello";
  }
```

Your `RequestMapping` should differ on at least one of the conditions; `path,method,params,headers,consumes,produces`

Comment: I believe it answered your query. Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

I needed the same url post mapping but it was giving me an error so I added different params and it worked for me

```
//url1 post mapping
@PostMapping(value = "/applicant/{step}", params = "validatedata")

//url2 post mapping
@PostMapping(value = "/applicant/{step}", params = "data")
```

if any of the below is different(as mentioned by the above answers)then you can have the same URL post mapping
**path,method,params,headers,consumes,produces**

In my case params was diffrent

Comment: can you pls quote the source for this statement - if any of the below is different(as mentioned by the above answers)then you can have the same URL post mapping path,method,params,headers,consumes,produces

I am having different method name but still I believe Spring is causing conflicts and throwing error. So want to verify from some source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that but you need to specify unique parameters signature in RequestMapping annotation:

```
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"!name", "!name2"})
public String action(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    // body
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "name")
public String action(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
    // body
}

}
```

`

Comment: thanks, but values are passed as parameter in post.. I want avoid that..

Comment: it's the only way

Comment: why did you took back acceptance for my answer? ;] it was the closest here, referring precisely to parameters part that you asked about.

Comment: you solution is best for params based post request