# Spring rest controller inheritance by params

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In our spring rest controller we would like to use the same mappings with different kind of parameters. 
To do this we created additional functions differentiated by mapping params. By doing so we are duplicating the number of functions. To avoid this I would like to use different controllers that should be loaded based on params values.

The question is can we

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1")
@RestController
public class Controller { 
    @PostMapping(value = "/event-calendar", params = {"externalToken", "event_type"})
    public ResponseEntity createEntityOfTypeToken(@RequestHeader(name = "X-Application-Authentication") String externalToken,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "event_type") String eventType) {

        MyEntity entity = service.createEntityOfType(
                userService.getTokenService(externalToken).getDeviceSerialNumber());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/event-calendar", params = {"serialId", "event_type"})
    public ResponseEntity createEntityOfTypeSerial(@RequestParam(value = "serialId") String serialId,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "event_type") String eventType) {

        MyEntity entity = service.createEntityOfType(serialId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587254/accessing-multiple-controllers-with-same-request-mapping

Comment: regarding this post it does not seem to be possible...

Comment: @Mr.Stef ,yes you can the way you have shown above. it should work

Answer (score 1):

Please refer

[create two method for same url pattern with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments)

[Spring - is possible to give same url in request mapping of post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519006/spring-is-possible-to-give-same-url-in-request-mapping-of-post-method)

P.S. not enough points to comment